# Magento 2 duplicated url's error / configurable products showing wrongly

Tags: magento, e-commerce

I am having a problem with configurable products in Magento 2.

there are too many problems happening at the same time, I hope you can help me.

1-One of the problems is that suddenly configurable products take position 0 so the categories start acting like "dynamics" because every time you refresh, the products with 0 positions start moving around. showing always different products.

2-I do not know why but the categories are broken, no matter what products I placed in them, some products appeared even after I clean the category up.

3-When I try to change the order or if I want to unassigned products from some categories, an error appears saying that some url's are duplicated.

Any of you have experienced this or similar?

thank you

Answer (score 0):

You might want to reindex if you have not done after you have made changes to category like adding/removing products in it etc.

bin/magento indexer:reset && bin/magento indexer:reindex && bin/magento c:f

You can use this module https://github.com/olegkoval/magento2-regenerate_url_rewrites  to regenerate URLs.
bin/magento ok:urlrewrites:regenerate